# How to display elements added programmatically on a storyboard?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have started learning Xamarin.iOS and tried adding a Search Bar element via Storyboards, and programmatically within a ViewController. I am struggling to understand why when I code the Search Bar instead of dragging and dropping it as outlined in the Microsoft documentation, I am unable to see it on the Storyboard?

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/searchbar

```
 searchBar = new UISearchBar(){
                Placeholder = "Enter your search Item",
                Prompt = "Search Entered here",
                ShowsScopeBar = true,
                ScopeButtonTitles = new string[]{ "Boston", "London", 
"SF" },
            };
```

What settings do I need apply to be able to see my hard coded elements on a Storyboard?

In terms of project structure, I just launched a default Single Page iOS template provided in Visual Studio, pasted the code into the ViewController class created by default and then tried to look for the element to appear on Main.storyboard. I understand that maybe perhaps I haven't set any kind of settings that allows the storyboard to see the "backend" ViewController code.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You're question is a little bit confusing.  Are you wanting to see the ```Storyboard``` broken down into the various ```Timeline```s and then the values of those ```Timeline```s as if it was a tree view?

Comment: No. It has nothing to do with Timeline at all or tree views. I have a default `Main.storyboard` and a `SearchBar` element I coded in the default `ViewController` class as outlined in my code. I am unable to see the `SearchBar` appear graphically on the `Main.storyboard` but when I launch an Iphone simulation it appears fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No,it is not possible to see a programmatically added component to appear within a storyboard.

A storyboard is a visual tool for laying out multiple application views and the transitions between them. Internally it is represented an  XML file.

The component added programmatically is a separate file and the storyboard is a separate xml file.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think you have a **misunderstanding** of `Storyboard`. **Storyboard is not a previewer.**

> A Storyboard is the visual representation of all the screens in an
>   application. It contains a sequence of scenes, with each scene
>   representing a View Controller and its Views. These views may contain
>   objects and controls that will allow your user to interact with your
>   application. This collection of views and controls (or subviews) is
>   known as a Content View Hierarchy.

`Storyboard` and `codes` you wrote in you `ViewController` are two different ways to create `UI` and your `business logic` of your project.

You can create your `searchBar` in `Storyboard` or using code in `Viewcontroller`. Once you run your project, the project will combine this two files so that you can see both elements your created in `Storyboard` and `codes`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! Misunderstood indeed.